# $\operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4_k)$ not irreducible (Ex. in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory book)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, deformation-theory

Exercise 1.5.8 from Robin Hartshorne's *Deformation Theory*:

**5.8. $\operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4_k)$** is not irreducible.
Consider the Hilbert scheme of zero-dimensional
closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^4_k$
of length $8$, the ground field $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed. There is one component of dimension $32$ that
has a nonsingular open subset corresponding to sets of eight distinct points. (I suppose that the author uses it as nontrivial fact)

We will
exhibit another component containing a nonsingular open subset of dimension $25$.

The Exercise comprises of four parts and I have problems with the first part:
(a) Let $R := k[x, y, z,w]$, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in this ring, and let $I = V + \mathfrak{m}^3$, where
$V$ is a $7$-dimensional subvector space of $\mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$. Let $B = R/I$, and let $Z$ be the
associated closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^4 $. Show that the set of all such $Z$, as the
point of its support ranges over $\mathbb{P}^4$, forms an irreducible $25$-dimensional subset of
the Hilbert scheme $H = \operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$.

How to show that the "set" of the $Z$'s as defined in (a) is irreducible?
Let call it $S \subset H$. The Hilbert scheme $H$ is constructed as closed subscheme of the Grassmanian defined by the vanishing of various determinants and is therefore we can endow the "set" $S$ as subscheme of $H$ with unique reduced scheme structure.

On the set level / on $k$-valued points $S(k)$ we can define canonically the map $p(k): S(k) \to \mathbb{P}^4(k)$ sending $Z$ the the unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_Z \subset k[x, y, z,w]$ associated to it as described in the construction above.
How can this idea be converted into a 'honest' map $p:S \to \mathbb{P}^4$? As soon as it is possible to construct such map $p$ we can use a result (reference ?) that for a proper surjective map $f: X \to Y$ with $Y$ and all fibers irreducible of same dimension, the scheme $X$ is irreducible, too.

Therefore the question reduces to 'How to construct $p:S \to \mathbb{P}^4$ from set map $p(k): S(k) \to \mathbb{P}^4(k)$?'
In addition note that that's just my suggestion how roughly I wanna to tackle this exercise. Maybe there are more effective ways to do it. All suggestions for alternative approaches are of course welcome!

Comment: If you know S(k) for any ring k (not only a field), and the map p(k) you define is functorial in k then you get that p is coming from a morphism of schemes from the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: @DannyOfek: That's true. But from the assumpions I was only able to construct the map $p(k)$ for $k=$ base field. I'm not sure if it is possible to prolonge from this piece of information it somehow to an arbitrary ring. What we assume is that $k$ is algebraically closed ... maybe that might be enough but I don't know...

Comment: Show trhat that set has dense subset you can parametrize by an irreducible variety using a regular map. Describe one of those ideals involves picking a point in an $A^4$ and the a subspace of dimension $7$ in a $10$ dimensional vector space, so a point in a grassmanian.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I'm a bit confused with the usage of word
 'set' in this context. When you say ' Show that set has dense 
subset... ' then you consider S as ' set ' literally as 'bare'
 underlying set forgetting the scheme structure which comprises of 
elements corresponding to prime ideals of the scheme? And where 
the closed points are exactly the k-valued points, because k is 
algebraically closed. It's known that the later is dense. Is then the set of $k$-valued points
 exactly the 'dense subset' you suggested in your last 
comment to consider?

Comment: If yes, then I'm not sure how to carry out the next step, 
namely to construct a *regular map* to an ireducible variety, 
presumingly to the product $\mathbb{A}^4 \times \mathbb{G}_{10,7}$.
 Which polynomials I should take to establish this regular map?

Comment: You described a construction that from a point $p$ in $A^4$ and a $7$-dimensional subspace of $(x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3$ produces a subscheme of $A^4$.  Show that that map is regular.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: 
I'm not sure if you rephrased the map in the construction correctly:
set theoretically it takes pair $(p, V)$ \to $Z:=
V(I = V + \mathfrak{m}^3) \subset \mathbb{P}^4$, where
$p \in A^4$ and $V$ is
a $7$-dimensional subspace of $ \mathfrak{m}_p^2/\mathfrak{m}_p^3 $ !
where the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_p \subset k[x,y,z,w]$ corresponds
to point $p$! Note that $\mathfrak{m}_p$ *varies* with $p$; therefore 
the $V$ is not neccessary always contained in
$(x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3$. $(x,y,z,w)$ is only one possible maximal ideal...

Comment: Therefore I not know how to show that this map is regular. recall, if we go back to old fashioned 
variety world, then by definition for 
two closed subvarieties $X \subset A^n, Y \subset A^m$ 
a map $f: X \to Y$ is called *regular* if is
the restriction of a polynomial map $A^n \to A^m$ given 
explicitely in the form $x \mapsto (f_1(x),..., f_m(x))$
where the $f_i$ are living in coordinate ring of $X$:
$k[x_1,..., x_n]/I(X)$.

Comment: Let come back to our case: we have as above $(p, V) \mapsto Z_{p,V}:= V(I = V + \mathfrak{m}^3) \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ and we want to show it's regular, that is of the form above. First problem: In which variety $X$ are the pairs $(p,V)$ living. $p \in A^4$, but note that $V$ varies with $p$ as I explained above, so $V$ is *not* an element of Grassmanian $\mathbb{G}_7((x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3)$ !...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: ok, I think I see now what you mean. You suggest to predecompose to this map from (a) - let call it $f$ - which as before maps $(p, V) \mapsto Z_{p,V}:= V(I = V + \mathfrak{m}^3) \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ - an operation which 'shifts' fiberwise $ V $ living in $  \mathfrak{m}_p^2/\mathfrak{m}_p^3$ to $ (x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3 $, right? And then check the regularity of the composition of this 'shift map' with $ f $. Is this the idea you suggest?

Comment: If yes, then the problem that I see is that this 'fiberwise shift' map of the $V$'s seems not to be a regular map in sense above, ie it is not given by polynomials. So I think the point is not if the is always an isomorphism between $ \mathfrak{m}_p^2/\mathfrak{m}_p^3$ to $(x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3 $   (which abstractly of course always exists), but how it evolve when we vary the point $p$. I think the problem with this approach is similar to the reason why the need connections in differential geometry: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Motivation

Comment: Abstractly tangent spaces of a manifold are at every point isomorphic but in order to impose a reasonable concept of differentiation we have to identify the tangent spaces, and this requires noncanonical choices from point to point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I have no idea what you are on about connections and such…

Let $(a_{i,j})$ be an arbitrary $7\times 3$ matrix of scalars, and let $f_1,\dots,,f_7$ be the linear combinations of monomials indicated in the rows of following table:
$$\begin{array}{*{12}{c}}
x^2 & y^2 & z^3 & w^2 & xy & xz & xw & yz & yw & zw \\ \hline
 1 & & & & & & & a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
 & 1 & & & & & & a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
 & & 1 & & & & & a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
 & & & 1 & & & & a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} \\
 & & & & 1 & & & a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} \\
 & & & & & 1 & & a_{6,1} & a_{6,2} & a_{6,3} \\
 & & & & & & 1 & a_{7,1} & a_{7,2} & a_{7,3} \\
\end{array}$$
Now let $a$, $b$, $c$ $d$ be four scalars and consider the ideal generated by the $7$ polynomials
$$
  f_1(x-a,y-b,z-d,w-d), \dots, f_7(x-a,y-b,z-d,w-d)
  $$
and all the polynomails $(x-a)^i(y-b)^j(z-c)^k(w-d)^l$ with $i+j+k+l=3$.

This gives you a $25$-dimensional family of ideals of colength $8$, parametrized by a point in $k^4\times M_{7,2}(k)$.

Viewing the entries of the matrix and the coordinates of the point $(a,b,c,d)$ as varibles now, the ideal generated by those seven polynials in $k[x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d,a_{1,1},\dots,a_{7,3}]$ define subscheme $Z$ in $k^4\times M_{7,2}(k)\times k^4$. The restriction of the map $p:k^4\times M_{7,2}(k)\times k^4\to k^4\times M_{7,2}(k)$ projecting on the first two factors to $Z$ is a map $Z\to k^4\times M_{7,2}(k)$ which is a flat family of subschemes of $k^4$, the fiber of $p$. The universal property of the Hilbert scheme tells you then that to this flat family corresponds a regular map into the Hilbert scheme.

Comment: alright I see the idea now, once having constructed this flat family the existence of the desired regular map to thr Hilbert scheme
follows automatically since it represents this functor. The association with connections from diffgeo in the comments above are nonsense as I see now ; previously I misunderstood your comments in that way that I thought that your intention was to construct explicitly / directly a regular map to the Hilbert scheme  'shifting fiberwise each subspace $ V \subset \mathfrak{m}_p^2/\mathfrak{m}_p ^3$ to $(x,y,z,w)^2/(x,y,z,w)^3$   and this strategy seemed

Comment: quite 'non algebraic' to me since there would be noncanonical choices be involved. And this reminded me a bit on this business with connections. That's it, but as I see was thinking in wrong direction...